# Why CGAL read mesh failed?

Tags: c++, cgal, cg

I read mesh (.off) by `CGAL::read_off(fin,mesh)` like examples, but it is failed!

this is my code:

```
#include<CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Polyhedron_3.h>
#include <CGAL/IO/OFF_reader.h>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel Kernel;
typedef CGAL::Polyhedron_3<Kernel> Polyhedron;
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  const char* filename ="../mesh000.off";
  std::ifstream input(filename);
  if (!input)
  {
    std::cerr << "Cannot open file " << std::endl;
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  std::vector<Kernel::Point_3> points;
  std::vector< std::vector<std::size_t> > polygons;
  if (!CGAL::read_OFF(input, points, polygons))
  {
    std::cerr << "Error parsing the OFF file " << std::endl;
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  Polyhedron mesh;
  if(!CGAL::read_off(input,mesh))
  {
      std::cerr << "Error Read OFF " << std::endl;
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

output:

```
Error Read OFF
```

It open mesh000.off successfully ,but why transfer to mesh failed!

Answer (score 1):

It means that your mesh is not a valid manifold surface. You can use the function [`is_polygon_soup_a_polygon_mesh()`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygon_mesh_processing/group__PMP__repairing__grp.html#ga8b9d12d817b5cc76f5a42d74eac75bf3) to check that and [`orient_polygon_soup()`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygon_mesh_processing/group__PMP__orientation__grp.html#gaadc5bac3072b11d2313e40043c729d0a) to make it manifold (but some edges might be duplicated and this would create some self-intersections).